# Reading Datagram Packet Incorrectly

Tags: java, arrays, datagram

I am reading a `DatagramPacket` into a `byte[]` as such:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[4 + size];
DatagramPacket request = new DatagramPacket(buffer, 4 + size);
receiver_Socket.receive(request);
```

I then print out the contents of the byte[].

```
String string = new String(buffer);
System.out.println(string);
```

The info that should be in the `DatagramPacket` is an `int` and 15 characters. `size` has been set to 15. However, when I print out the `byte[]` I just get 4 random symbols.

I printed out the `byte[]` right before I sent it and the output was: a random symbol, followed by the correct 15 characters... I am certain I am sending over 19 bytes as I also checked this value prior to sending the `DatagramPacket`.

Would anyone know what is going on here?

Thank you.

Comment: Which charset are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure, I didn't specify a charset. I also noticed that if I store the `byte[]` in a `ByteBuffer` and use `getInt()` the value is completely wrong. I just get some large number...

Comment: Do you mean `String string = new String(buffer,4,size);`? (see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte[],%20int,%20int%29 ) Though, specifying a charset is always a good idea.